# iterate over multimap <string, map <string,int> >

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

i want to iterate over all items in a multimap `<string,map<string,int>>` but just once for each Key, but i cant make it work, here is the code im using to iterate:

```
for(multimap <string, map <string, int> >::iterator it = myMultimap.begin(); it != myMultimap.end(); it =myMultimap.upper_bound(it->first)){

    //i read that myMultimap.upper_bound(it->first) get the elements of the same key

    pair< multimap <string,map <string, int> >::iterator , multimap <string,map <string, int> >::iterator > ret;
    ret = myMultimap.equal_range(it->first);

    for(multimap <string, map <string, int> >::iterator it2 = ret.first; it2 != ret.second; it2++){


    //here i just want to print map <string , int>
    cout << (*it2).second.first << endl;
    cout << (*it2).second.second << endl;

    }
}
```

when i run it i get `class std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>’ don't have a member called ‘first’` and same thing for second.second. Sorry about my english is not my mother language.

Comment: `multimap <string, map <string, int> > it2` is missing `::iterator`, `cout << (*it).second.first` should be `it2`, and `myMultimap.upper_bound(it->first)` should have `it =` prefixed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make things easier for ourselves to start with

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> InnerMap;
typedef std::multimap<std::string, InnerMap> StringMap;

StringMap myMultimap;
```

Now, that outer loop

```
for (StringMap::iterator it = myMultimap.begin(); it != myMultimap.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "[" << it->first << "]:";
    for (InnerMap::iterator it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); ++it2)
    {
        std::cout << " " << it2->first << ":" << it2->second;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

We can also, if you have C++11, make things simpler by using auto

```
for (auto it = myMultimap.begin(); it != myMultimap.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "[" << it->first << "]:";
    for (auto it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); ++it2)
    {
        std::cout << " " << it2->first << ":" << it2->second;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

What we're doing:

```
for (StringMap::iterator it = myMultimap.begin(); it != myMultimap.end(); ++it)
```

This iterates across all of the `std::pair<std::string /*key*/, InnerMap /*value*/>` elements that actually make up the outer multimap. If you have one key twice, you'll see both entries.

`it->first` is the `std::string` key for the current multimap entry, `it->second` is the `InnerMap` value of the current entry.

```
    for (InnerMap::iterator it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); ++it2)
```

This iterates over the `std::pair<std::string, int>` InnerMap elements of the map that is the value of this multimap slot.

--- EDIT ---

Ultimately, using C++11 you could use range based for (not sure why I thought this would be messier)

```
// use 'auto&' so we take a reference instead of a copy.
for (auto& it : myMultimap)
{
    std::cout << "[" << it.first << "]:";
    for (auto it2 : it.second)
    {
        std::cout << " " << it2.first << ":" << it2.second;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Note that, in this case, we now use "." instead of "->". This is because we're actually seeing every element (`std::pair<...>`) in the multimap/map, rather than a simple iterator. That is, `it` is of type `std::pair<std::string, InnerMap>&` and `it2` is of type `std::pair<std::string, int>&`.

Comment: There's also the range based-for which is cleaner.

Comment: Is it actually cleaner with a multimap?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Comment: evaluating .end() every iteration is also wasteful. if you aren't using rangedfor you can define end to a temp var so there's only one evaluation of .end() worst case rather than O(n). http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i neet to do the outer 1 time for each key, and if i do that on your code i cant go throw the inner cycle.

Comment: @user193138 Uh, that's coding standards for maintaining LLVM code not a general guide for good optimization, e.g. it also suggests ordering code so that you have `if (abnormalcase) return 0;` which tends to produce code with a lot of branch misses. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @DavidSttivendAngel Are you trying to aggregate the keys? E.g. if your  multipmap contains "hello" twice, once with {"dog":1, "cat":2} and once with {"fish":3, "cheese":4}, it will do the inner loop for both sub-maps at the same time?

Comment: @kfsone yes!! im sorry if i don't explained myself very well.
example: 
input: (A,(1,2)), (A,(3,4)) output: print A outer cycle,then print 1,2 then 3,4 inner cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
   map<string, int>::iterator in;

 for(multimap <string, map <string, int> >::iterator it = myMultimap.begin(); it != myMultimap.end(); it =myMultimap.upper_bound(it->first)){



        pair< multimap <string,map <string, int> >::iterator , multimap <string,map <string, int> >::iterator > ret;
        ret = myMultimap.equal_range(it->first);

        for(multimap <string, map <string, int> >::iterator it2 = ret.first; it2 != ret.second; it2++){

            //get the map with begin() and assign it to an iterator
            in = it2->second.begin();
            cout << in->first << " "<< in->second << endl;


        }
    }
```